# Wrap Around/Toroidal? Distance

Tags: differential-geometry, geometric-topology

I am struggling to get a distance metric that works on a plane that repeats/tiles itself similar to the way a walking on a torus works. An analogy to the Euclidean distance between 2 points but on a torus.

Comment: It may help first to look for such a metric on a circle.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus#Flat_torus

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the plane ($\mathbb{R}^2$) is tiled by $1\times 1$ squares, so if you have two points $(x_1,x_2)$ and $(y_1,y_2)$, their "torus distance" will be the same as the torus distance between $(x_1,x_2)$ and $(y_1+n,y_2+m)$ where $n,m$ are integers.

Let's use $\operatorname{frac}(x)$ to denote the fractional part of $x$ in the sense of the difference between $x$ and $x$ rounded down.  So for example, $\operatorname{frac}(4.2)=0.2$ and $\operatorname{frac}(-4.2)=0.8$.  Something we know is that the distance metric should satisfy
$$d((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2))=d((\operatorname{frac}(x_1),\operatorname{frac}(x_2)),(\operatorname{frac}(y_1),\operatorname{frac}(y_2)))$$
since this represents shifting the two points to lie in the unit square $[0,1)\times[0,1)$.
Another thing we know is that the distance metric should satisfy
$$d((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2))=d((x_1-y_1,x_2-y_2),(0,0))$$
since translating the plane shouldn't change the metric.  Putting these together, we have
$$d((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2))=d((\operatorname{frac}(x_1-y_1),\operatorname{frac}(x_2-y_2)),(0,0)).$$
What remains is to figure out what $d((x,y),(0,0))$ is when $0\leq x<1$ and $0\leq y<1$.  The nearest translates of $(0,0)$ to $(x,y)$ are $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$, and $(1,1)$, which are the four corners of the unit square.  So, we have
$$d((x,y),(0,0)) = \min\left\{\sqrt{x^2+y^2},\sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2},\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2},\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2}\right\}$$
which can be simplified to
$$d((x,y),(0,0)) = \sqrt{\left(\min\{x,1-x\}\right)^2 +\left(\min\{ y,1- y\}\right)^2 }.$$

Therefore, the full torus metric can be written as
$$d((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)) = \sqrt{\left(\min\{\operatorname{frac}(x_1-y_1), 1-\operatorname{frac}(x_1-y_1)\}\right)^2 +\left(\min\{\operatorname{frac}(x_2-y_2),1- \operatorname{frac}(x_2-y_2)\}\right)^2 }.$$